# Use :has pseudoclass in tailwind on hover

Tags: css, tailwind-css, pseudo-class

I have a component with the following structure:

```
<li key={index} className="custom--item group">
<p className="font-medium mb-2">Person No.{index + 1}</p>
<Button
  variant="danger"
  size="sm"
  {...getRemoveProps(index)}
  type="submit"
  className="custom--delete mt-2"
  >
      <UilTrashAlt className="text-red-300" />
  </Button>
</li>
```

I'm using Tailwind for styling, and I wanted to achieve the next feature:
When hovering on the delete button, the parent(`<li>...</li>`) opacity should change to 40%.

To achieve that I used this CSS (added to tailwind.css):

```
.custom--item:has(.custom--delete:hover) {
    opacity: 50%;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

So I have achieved what I wanted, and now **my question is**: Can I do the same without adding the `custom--item` and `custom--delete` classes in the tailwind.css?

I've sumbled upon [this discussion](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/10206), and tried using the given example, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Based on the example given in that discussion you linked to, I was easily able to make something like `[&:has(button:hover)]:bg-red-500` work, for your given structure. So all that would be left to do, is to replace the `bg-red-500` part with a class that applies your desired opacity and transition ...

Comment: I was trying to get the button with its classes, and apparently if i add `[&:has(button.group/delete:hover)]` class, then it will not work, but removing the `/delete` it works. So thanks!